# Java Method returns initialize variable, instead of final value of variable.

Tags: java

Well, I'm new in java, and i'm making a method which objective is to return the average grades of a student, but instead of returning the final value I'm getting the initialize value of the variable that is returning the method.

This is the method:

```
private int promedio;
private int average;

StudentInfo() {
    this.average = 0; ///THIS IS WHAT THE METHOD IS RETURNING!!!
    this.totalPercent = 0;
}

public int finalAverage() {
    for (int i = 0, n = quantity-1; i <= n; i++){
        average = average + (percentage[i]/100)*(notes[i]) ;  ///THIS IS WHAT IT SHOULD RETURN!!!                  
    }
    return average;
}  

 System.out.println("El estudiante " + nombre + " cuenta con un promedio de " + myObj.finalAverage() + "." );

    if (myObj.finalAverage() < 3){
        System.out.println("El estudiante perdio la materia.");            
    }else{
        System.out.println("¡FELICIDADES! Ha pasado la materia.");
```

Thank you very much for your help, and have nice day. :D

Comment: where is the flying code supposed to be, what are `n`, `quantity`, etc. Can you post a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Percentage is probably an int. Dividing by 100, an int too, uses **integer division**. 99/100 == 0! Divide by 100 at the end, or use **double** (less nice).

Comment: true and considering OP is trying to find the "average" surely he/she should opt for your suggestion of using a double type.

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw could be some CS course. I.o. average total*100/count or such is feasable. Floating point is not liked in CS.